# Change the "href" and "src" attributes using jQuery based on condition

Tags: jquery

I have the following links:

```
<script src="/WebResource.php?d=FViz" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="WebResource.php?d=FViz" type="text/javascript"></script>

<img src="/Images/top.png">
<img src="Images/top.png">

<link href="/Skins/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How do i insert in all of "src" and "href" attributes which belong to "script" "link" and "img" tags the "http://example.com/" at the beginning of the link if the link does not start with "http://" or "www.".

So in the end the final result should be like this

```
<script src="http://example.com/WebResource.php?d=FViz" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://example.com/WebResource.php?d=FViz" type="text/javascript"></script>

<img src="http://example.com/Images/top.png">
<img src="http://example.com/Images/top.png">

<link href="http://example.com/Skins/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I must stress that it must be done using jQuery in the user browser after the page has been loaded and not on the server side.

Sorry that i do not have any base examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI, this type of URL fix-up is usually done server-side because the client does not have full control of this kind of stuff.

You cannot use client-side javascript/jQuery to modify existing `<script>` tags in your page.  They will have already been parsed and loaded by the time you could try to modify them.  You could insert new `<script>` tags with the appropriate `src` values if you needed to.

You can modify image `src` values with jQuery, but I'm wondering if there's a much better way to solve the issue you have.

---

If what you're really trying to do is to change the default path for relative URIs in your page, then you can use the `<base>` tag in the `<head>` section to change all the non-absolute URIs to use a different default path.

```
<base href="http://example.com">
```

---

Using jQuery, `<img>` `src` properties could be modified like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").each(function() {
        // get raw .src attribute
        var src = this.getAttribute("src");
        if (src.slice(0, 7) !== "http://") {
            // make sure there's a leading "/"
            if (src.charAt(0) !== "/") {
                src = "/" + src;
            }
            // add domain
            src = "http://example.com" + src;
        }
        this.src = src;
    });
});
```

---

Since script tags have already been loaded (or attempted to be loaded) before you can get to them with your own script, the only thing you could do with the script tags is to create new script tags with the desired paths and then reinsert them.  This likely creates loading order issues because the new script tags will load asynchronously.

Comment: I did not know that there was such thing as  "<base> tag in the <head>" It worked with that without the need for the jq. Now i can do this on the server side :) thanks a lot for the suggestion @jfriend00

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.each($("[src]"),function()
{
    if(($(this).attr("src").indexOf("http")>-1) || ($(this).attr("src").indexOf("www")>-1))
    { }
    else {
        $(this).attr('src',"http://www.example.com"+$(this).attr('src'));
    }
});
```

Comment: It's best if you add some commentary and not just toss code out there.